# Custom User Registration Form not showing

Tags: plugins

I need help to show my own created user registration form. Whatever I do, WP 5.9 is always showing the default registration form.

I have used many different plugins to create a customer registration form and followed all steps described in the plugins. Whatever I do, WP always shows the default registration form. Is there a way/setting to replace the default form?

Thank you so much,
Hump

Comment: have you previously modified files in `wp-admin`/`wp-includes`? Custom registration forms don't normally replace the original registration form, rather they add a new form elsewhere that you can direct users to. The same with custom logins. Some plugins then provide redirects to those who visit the original registration/login. Keep in mind this is a programming stack so any answer you get may require PHP knowledge to understand and use

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have your custom registration form set up to its own URL, such as `/custom-register-page/` or something like it, then you can use the following code to change the register URL on the default WP login page:

```
add_filter( 'register_url', 'update_register_url' );
function update_register_url( $url ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $url;
    }
    return "/custom-register-page/";
}
```

Add this code to your template's `functions.php` file, if that makes sense, or [create a plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/plugins/) to use this code. Make sure to update the code to use your custom register page URL.